# Parent not sizing to child's padding

Tags: html, css

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Keisz/ <-- simple example

This codepen mimics an issue I'm having. I want the parent elements (outer and inner containers) to fully encompass their content (the content div) - I'm at my wit's end of how to accomplish this and I'm almost certain it's a simple fix.

Applying

```
box-sizing:border-box;
```

to the child element is not what I want. I want the parent to resize to child, not the other way around.

Any help you could provide would be most appreciated!

EDIT: I think there is some confusion. I want the parent to dynamically resize to contain the largest child width + padding. The max-height is also a requirement, sadly. :(

Comment: I think you need to set position:relative on the parent. Or maybe was the child... float:left might do the trick too, or both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the height and width attributes from the content div. Voila

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pluAk/

Comment: That works great, but why does it work? It feels counter-intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you apply `box-sizing:border-box;` the parent will not take into account the padding while wrapping around the child divs. You need to apply this style. Otherwise the code you've posted works just fine (it neglects the 20px padding on the innermost div and the parent wraps around the width of the child div minus the padding on thew child div).
Just remove the `max-height` from the parent div and you are good to go

Comment: Can you provide me with a Fiddle, please? I can't reproduce your results. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is the ultimate purpose of why you are doing this, but assuming that it would help, this is an idea

```
#innerContainer {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;

}
```

[***FIDDLE***](http://jsfiddle.net/XxBLD/)